# Understanding withtracker() component in Meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I was trying to learn meteor and not very familiar with this pattern of HOC (it's meteor.js with react).

I was going though their offical docs of tutorials. Here is what they did ([You can click here to visit the page](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections))

They imported following package in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'; 
import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';
```

Then there is a simple to do class App extends component wrapped by this HOC

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  return {
    tasks: Tasks.find({}).fetch(),
  };
})(App);
```

The official docs for the same says

> The wrapped App component fetches tasks from the Tasks collection and
>   supplies them to the underlying App component it wraps as the tasks
>   prop. It does this in a reactive way, so that when the contents of the
>   database change, the App re-renders, as we'll soon see!

Now this language isn't exactly alien to me but I am having hard to comprehend and understand it. So Can someone explain me the same?

To be specific what is The wrapped `App component` fetches tasks and supplies it to `underline app` component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A higher order component is in the most basic form a function that takes a component type as input and returns a component class that wraps the input component and adds functionality to it.

Usually the signature is function that takes the argument to apply to the wrapped component which returns a HOC as described above so you can use it with multiple components.

Here is a very basic example that shows an error message if the component it's used on or any of it's child components throw an exception:

```
const catchError = ({ errorMessage }) => InputComponent => class extends Component {
  render() {
       try {
        return <InputComponent {...this.props} />;
       } catch {
          return <div>{errorMessage}</div>
       }
  }
}

const ComponentWithErrorMessage = catchError({ errorMessage: 'Whoops!' })(MyComponent);

// This is the same as the following, the first just immediately invokes the returned function
const whoopsErrorHoc = catchError({ errorMessage: 'Whoops!' });
const ComponentWithWhoopsError = whoopsErrorHoc(MyComponent);
```

The meteor HOC will be a bit more complicated but the idea is the same. It receives a reference to the meteor Task store and will return a component that re-renders the input component whenever the data changes in the store and add the data to the props of that component.

Comment: David, Thanks,
referring to the same link and following the same steps mention in the meteor article, i am having tough time get data on my HTML when I do this in database 

`db.tasks.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });` (although it logs ninserted:1). Can you help me understand where I would be going wrong. The git for the same with the current commit is https://github.com/irohitb/Meteor

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, I'm not very familiar with meteor. It seems that for some reason you're not receiving updates from the server but I'm unsure why.